# Prevent loading a dll from GAC

Tags: c#, gac

I have an Aspx page with no .cs file. This page is using a dll file which is already in the GAC of my machine.
I have a new version of this dll, but I don't want to change anything in the GAC. Can I make this aspx page load the dll from my bin directory and override the GAC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Just put new assembly to folder where your application binaries are and use assembly redirection [Assembly Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And make sure your assembly version has changed.